# Show posts by a custom post author

Tags: posts, customization, author

I have a listing site and various authors create custom posts (job_listing) 
On the listing post itself, I would like to show the links to the last 5 NORMAL blog posts by that author

Is this anywhere near right?

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'job_listing',
    'author' => get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )
);
$listing_post = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $listing_post->have_posts() ){
    while( $listing_post->have_posts() ){
        $listing_post->the_post();
        the_permalink();
    }
}
// reset $post global to original value
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Then after this query, how do I then output the result in a list of anchor links?